# Wrapping a .net DLL for use in classic ASP and app.config

Tags: .net, asp-classic

I have a .net component which we need to access from a classic asp application.

I have written a com wrapper for this however have encountered an issue, the problem is that when I access the object from the classic asp page the settings that are being loaded are the defaults, not the ones that are defined in the app.config file.

This poses a problem as one of the settings in environment specific and defaults to the dev environment so now that we have the component in test we have spotted that its still interacting with the dev environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your wrapper must be a COM+ component, am I right?

I'd a similar issue. The trick is to ensure your COM+ package are reading your configuration file from the right folder.

In COM+, right click over your package, then **Properties**.

Click Activation, and fill the **Application Root Directory** field with the path of your dll files and configuration file (they must be in same folder).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Ahhh - I worked around the isuse by passing the settings in from the calling application instead - but this makes sense!

Thanks